# Sending image from client on java to server on python

Tags: java, python, mysql, sockets, server

I have been trying to create a program that runs a client in Java and the server in Python. **My overall goal is to upload a picture from the client on Java to the server on Python and store it on a mysql server.** I haven't tried yet to convert from image on Python to blob on mysql and already got stuck in the uploading to python phase. This is the following code:

Client: (java)

```
        client.send("upload##user##pass##"); //this is how i know that upload    request has been sent.
        String directory = "/home/michael/Pictures/"+field.getText();// a valid directory of a picture.
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(directory));
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", client.socket.getOutputStream());//sending the picture via socket.
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the server:(Python)

```
 elif mar[0]=="upload":##this is how i know that the request is to upload

  buf = ''
  while len(buf)<4:
     buf += clientsock.recv(4-len(buf))
  size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)
  print "receiving %s bytes" % size

  with open('tst.jpg', 'wb') as img:
      while True:
         data = clientsock.recv(1024)
         if not data:
           break
         img.write(data)
  print 'received, yay!'
```

This code actually doesn't work and prints ridiculous amount of bytes that I want to send (around 2 gb for the picture) I have not been working a lot with the server/client so this code perhaps is awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see that you sending image size before sending the image, but in Python code you're reading 4 bytes image size first.
You need to add sending of image size in your Java code:

```
try {
    OutputStream outputStream = client.socket.getOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
    // get the size of image
    byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();
    outputStream.write(size);
    outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    outputStream.flush();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for commenting. 
Yet, it runs this error: 

Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.io.OutputStream to org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream

These two types seem to be not the same for some reason on the first line.

Comment: Try to import java.io.OutputStream instead of org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream